# Mac OS/X, Grep and Whitespace issues

Tags: regex, macos, grep, whitespace

I am trying to use GREP on a text file in OS/X as a test.  It is known to contain the following text, including whitespace characters.

```
(10) Business Day
```

My regex search pattern is as follows:

```
[\(][0-9]{1,3}[\)] business day
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
$ grep -Eoi '[\(][0-9]{1,3}[\)] business day' *.txt
```

If I remove "day" from the above, I get this:

```
$ grep -Eoi '[\(][0-9]{1,3}[\)] business' *.txt
(10) Business
```

Which is the expected output from egrep -oi or grep -Eoi for the above line.

Neither this:

```
$ grep -Eoi '[\(][0-9]{1,3}[\)]\sbusiness\sday' *.txt
```

Nor this:

```
$ grep -Eoi '[\(][0-9]{1,3}[\)] business\sday' *.txt
```

Nor this:

```
$ grep -Eoi '[\(][0-9]{1,3}[\)][[:space:]]business[[:space:]]day' *.txt
```

Nor this:

```
$ grep -Eoi '[\(][0-9]{1,3}[\)] business[[:space:]]day' *.txt
```

yield the desired result, which is:

```
(10) Business Day
```

Instead, they yeild this:

```
$
```

(nothing)

I have wasted hours pounding my head on my desk for hours over this.  Grep is clearly not rocket surgery, so what am I missing here?????

Comment: Which version of `grep` you using? `grep -V`

Comment: @suku Native grep to OS/X.  -V output (which I looked at earlier while fighting with this thing) gave me this:  grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

Comment: Can you run `cat -v` on the source file and make sure there's nothing weird hiding there. (or `od -a` if that is ambiguous). I am suspicious that what you think of as whitespace has something funky there instead.

Comment: What about `business.*day`?

Comment: @vielmetti $cat -v test2.txt (10) business day^M  <-- I think it's probably the ^M that's causing it here.  I ran a $ echo "(10) Business Day" | grep -Eoi "[\(][0-9]{1,3}[\)] business day" to see what would happen, and I got the desired result.  

The text file was saved from Word as a text file; so I think the problem is in the encoding...

Comment: @vielmetti when I cat -v the ORIGINAL file containing the known text (it's quite large, I find this: "(10) Business ^M
 Day" Which, I expect, is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.  I need to thank vielmetti and suku for pointing me in the right direction, though.

The problem was multiple-fold.

First, the problem was in relation to the encoding of the text file when saved from a Word document on the Mac operating system.  You need to save it as MS-DOS format, and DO NOT insert line breaks.

Once that got resolved, the command started finding the desired text, and, once I had figured out the MACScript approach so I could put the grep command into vba properly, everything fell into place.

So, to review - when saving a MS-Word document on the MAC as a Text file, make sure to use MS-DOS formatting withOUT line feeds.

Here's the VBA command to save it:

```
        Document.SaveAs FileName:=filePath & docName & ".txt", _
                        FileFormat:=wdFormatText, _
                        LockComments:=False, _
                        Password:="", _
                        AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
                        WritePassword:="", _
                        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
                        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _
                        SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, _
                        SaveFormsData:=False, _
                        SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, _
                        Encoding:=437, _
                        InsertLineBreaks:=False, _    
                        AllowSubstitutions:=False, _
                        LineEnding:=wdCROnly
```

The key settings  InsertLineBreaks := False and, potentially, LineEnding:=wdCROnly.